# What's the best place to put all logic about generating a report in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-organization, project-organization

I have many models which I use to obtain data and generate a report.

The report doesn't need to be stored, i.e. it's not an active record.

But certainly there's like 80 lines of code which generate the data for the report.

Where should I put those lines?

They are currently in the controller but since controller should be thin, I'm not sure if that's the best place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create a directory in app called `reports`, and put all of my reports in there.

Everything in the app directory in rails can be found as long as the filename and class follow the normal convention.

For example, if you have the following in `app/reports/example_report.rb`:

```
class ExampleReport
  def initialize
    ...
  end
end
```

You will be able to use it from your controllers as such:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def something
    example = ExampleReport.new
    ...
  end
end
```

Reports that rely on models are considered part of your application's domain, which is why I recommend the app directory. The ease of adding subdirectories in app means that you can maintain a logical separation of the different roles in your application. It shouldn't be hard to guess where the implementation for something is. Controllers are in `app/controllers`, models are in `app/models`, so it follows that reports are in `app/reports`. And for example, if you were to add generic service classes to your app, they could go in `app/services`.

In contrast, they do not belong in lib, because they cannot function in a generic fashion. To further this point, only code that you could envision being used in *any* rails project belongs in the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that something like that would belong in a helper method/methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you have business logic not tied to persistence, you can place it in models without inheriting from ActiveRecord. See:

- [Making ActiveRecord Models Thin](https://solnic.codes/2011/08/01/making-activerecord-models-thin/)
- [ActiveRecord is the problem](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-12-30-active-record-considered-harmful#activerecord_is_the_problem)

Answer (score -1):

`Helpers` should be better place to put that code,

Also make sure the pure logic related code to fetching/processing data should still go to `model`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't helpers designed to define methods which format data? as printing strings or numbers with different formats? Should they manage logic about the data? You say that should go to my model but what if I don't have a model associated with that report? Should I create a non-persisted model for each report I want to generate?